# how to make calculation with scope variable within ng-repeat | Angular Js

Tags: angularjs, scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have ng-repeat on a table row `<tr>` in which a td are filled out by ng-repeat. one of the `<td>` i have to make a simple calculation like that:

```
 <td>{{ (total.drawerAmount + total.totalReturns ) - total.totalWithd }}</td>
```

this returns **0.0005000000019208528** while it should return **0**, meanwhile it works fine when i make it in this form:

```
<td>{{ total.drawerAmount + total.totalReturn }}</td>
```

please can someone explain why it works when i only put two variable and it go wrong when i put three variable in the calculation? Thanks in advance

Comment: try without the brackets (). + and - will result in the same number with or without brackets.

Comment: same result even when i removed the brackets

Comment: Ok, sure, that is one step. Next put simple number in the {{ }}, like this {{ 5+ 7 - 2}} and see the result. I bet it calculates fine. This will lead you to the conclusion that the variables values are not Ok.

Comment: What are the numeric values of each of your variables?

Comment: @RaniRadcliff i tried new values and they are exactly : `{9900 + 1000 - 1000 } , the result is `8900.0001`

Comment: i solved the problem by removing the quotations from the json around them, it was making errors because the browser was reading them as strings maybe?